# Check Existence Before Creating - Select, Insert, on conflict return

Tags: postgresql-9.4, concurrency, unique-constraint, bulk-insert

I've the following code that creates mapbox vector tiles and inserts them for storage. In the final code each xyz tile will be unique. Before the below code I would like to check the storage table to see if the xyz tile exists and return it instead of running the code and having a conflict. However, regardless of conflicts it should still return the tiles (in this case two tiles):

```
WITH 
mvtgeom AS
(
SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((0 0, 10 0, 10 5, 0 -5, 0 0))'),
ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(0, 0), ST_Point(4096, 4096)),
4096, 0, false)
),

mvtgeom1 AS
(
SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((0 0, 10 0, 10 5, 0 -5, 0 0))'),
ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(0, 0), ST_Point(4096, 4096)),
4096, 0, false)
)

INSERT INTO tile(dataset_id, z, x, y, mvt, build_time, use_count) 
    SELECT 311, 2, 6, 12, ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom), 0.323, 4
    FROM   mvtgeom
UNION
    SELECT 312, 2, 6, 12, ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom1), 0.323, 4
    FROM   mvtgeom1

RETURNING *;
```

Any suggestions welcome, I'm not whether it would be safer to always create the tiles and check on conflict at the end? There will be multiple concurrent queries and I'd like to make it safe.

Comment: The only way to ensure no duplicates are inserted is to create a unique index. Then `insert .. on conflict` either with `do nothing` or `update` whatever you need.

Comment: Agreed, but surely there is a way to check for a "tile" and return that, else create then insert?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15950324/

Comment: *"each xyz tile will be unique"* What's unique exactly? Show your `UNIQUE` constraint. What if one tile is found, but not the other? What binds the two together? Why not insert them separately? `mvtgeom` and `mvtgeom1` are exactly the same in your example. Typo? Also, please always declare your version of Postgres.

Comment: apologies, there is a unique key constraint on dataset_id + z + x + y . Yes in this example the tile ```mvtgeom``` and ```mvtgeom1``` are the same but this will not be the case. How would you go about inserting sepeartely? The version is 9.4 .